# Geolocation has no Method isLocationOperational

Tags: dart, flutter

i have implement the geolocation Plugin like the instruction says, but when i wanted to use `Geolocation.isLocationOperational()`. The Method isn't defined.

The Quellcode where i use it:

```
import 'package:geolocation/geolocation.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void checkGPS() async{
final GeolocationResult result = await Geolocation.isLocationOperational();
if(result.isSuccessful) {
  print("Success");
} else {
  print("Fail");
}}
```

in the xml file i added the permission i needed.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

someone have a idea what i make wrong?

Comment: Have you run "flutter packages get" ?

Comment: i did, but the problem is there anyway

Comment: I've downloaded this plugin and it worked fine. check if this file exists "$FLUTTER_DIRECTORY/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocation-0.2.1/lib/geolocation.dart". where this error appeared. in the console or your IDE?

Comment: By Dart analysis. when i code the method is underlined in red

Comment: i find my Mistake. thanks for help